# Latex: How to add dashed lines for matrix?

Tags: matrices, line, vertical, horizontal

In a $4\times5$ matrix,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,bm,mathdots}

\begin{document}
$$\left(\begin{matrix}
1  &2   &-1  &3  &4\\
0  &1   &3   &-2 &-1\\
0  &0   &0   &0  &0\\
0  &0   &0   &0  &0\\   
\end{matrix}\right) $$  

\end{document}
```

I want to add a horizontal dashed line below (1,1) element, and a vertical dashed line to the right of (2,1) element, and a long horizontal dashed line below (2,2) element until (2,5) element. How to solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! PLease show us, what you try so far. It seems that use of the `nicematrix` be a good possibilities.

Comment: I want to add a dotted line representing the ladder to a ladder matrix

Comment: This you already said in question. Show us asmal document with your matrix. See question on site  tagged `nicematrix`.

Comment: In this ladder matrix, the elements of (2,1) and lines 3-4 are all 0, and other elements are not.

Comment: \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,bm,mathdots}

\begin{document}
$$\left(\begin{matrix}
1  &2   &-1  &3  &4\\
0  &1   &3   &-2 &-1\\
0  &0   &0   &0  &0\\
0  &0   &0   &0  &0\\ 
\end{matrix}  \right) $$ 
 
\end{document}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`arydshln`](//ctan.org/pkg/arydshln) to draw dashed lines (horizontal and vertical):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{arydshln}
\setlength{\dashlinegap}{1pt}
\setlength{\dashlinedash}{1pt}

\begin{document}

\[
  \left(
    \begin{array}{@{} c c c c c @{}}
      1 & 2 & -1 &  3 &  4 \\
      \cdashline{1-1}
      0 & \multicolumn{1}{: c}{1} &  3 & -2 & -1 \\
      \cdashline{2-5}
      0 & 0 &  0 &  0 &  0 \\
      0 & 0 &  0 &  0 &  0
    \end{array}
  \right)
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!