# How to draw these two lines?

Tags: equations

How to draw these two lines?

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    Trans_{z_{n-1}}(d_n) = \begin{bmatrix}
    
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & d_{n}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1

    \end{bmatrix}
    
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

My current version is like this:

[image]

Comment: Off topic comments: (1) ltxdoc is designed for typesetting tex documentation, not math articles; I would switch to just article. (2) Equation environments aren't allowed to have blank lines. (3) `Trans` is the product of 5 separate variables; `\mathrm{Trans}` would be better.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79134/a-matrix-with-labels-dashed-lines?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C61.0505 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/581086/latex-how-to-add-dashed-lines-for-matrix?r=SearchResults&s=4%7C60.2237

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the `tabularray` package like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \text{Trans}_{z_{n-1}}(d_n) = 
    \begin{+bmatrix}[
      hline{Y} = {solid},
      vline{Y} = {solid}
    ]
      1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
      0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
      0 & 0 & 1 & d_{n}\\
      0 & 0 & 0 & 1
    \end{+bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe `\text{Trans}` -> `\mathrm{Trans}`,  but anyway +1!,

Answer (score 6):

With `nicematrix`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\[ 
\mathrm{Trans}_{z_{n-1}}(d_n) = 
\begin{bNiceArray}{ccc|c}[margin]
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & d_{n}\\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bNiceArray}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't know about `nicematrix` Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    Trans_{z_{n-1}}(d_n) = \left[\begin{array}{ccc@{\enskip\vrule\enskip}c}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & d_{n}\\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
    \end{array}\right]
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe with the stared version? OP doesn't have numbering (1) in bottom-right. Nice answer anyway.

Comment: @gildux Thanks for the comment